# Multiline variable with spaces, adding each line to an array

Tags: bash, shell, quoting

I have a problem I can't seem to figure out..
I'm making a script I will run in OSX to help me stay connected to open wifi hotspots.
I am reading all surrounding wifi networks into a muntiline variable.
These wifi networks have sometimes spaces in their names, which presents a problem for me.
I want to loop through this multiline variable that contains spaces and add each line as it is to a new array cell.
Adding my code below.
Anyone that can help me sort this out?

```
#Looks for available networks
netarray=(`airport -s |
awk '$NF=="NONE"{print}' | 
cut -c 1-32,51-54 | 
sort -r -n -k 1.34,1.36 | 
awk '{$NF=""; print}' | 
sed -e 's/ $//' `)

#Test text added here
echo "netarray below"
echo "$netarray"
echo "cell 0 below"
echo ${netarray[0]}
echo "cell 1 below"
echo ${netarray[1]}
echo ""
#Until here
```

This gives me this output (See that TPE Free is cut):

```
netarray below
TPE Free HP-Print-93-LaserJet 1102
cell 0 below
TPE
cell 1 below
Free
```

airport -s gives me this output currently:

```
                        SSID BSSID             RSSI CHANNEL HT CC SECURITY (auth/unicast/group)
                   fuck this 00:1f:1f:27:e4:ac -79  11      N  -- WEP
                       BigA2 34:08:04:c3:9a:14 -85  11      N  US WPA(PSK/AES,TKIP/TKIP) WPA2(PSK/AES,TKIP/TKIP) 
                    TPE Free 78:cd:8e:a6:ff:30 -90  10      N  T9 NONE
                     CHT3826 b0:b2:dc:c3:91:77 -82  11      Y  -- WPA2(PSK/AES/AES) 
                          KK 00:e0:4c:ac:e1:05 -84  11      N  -- WEP
                 perfectidea f8:1a:67:53:eb:da -79  9,-1    Y  -- WPA2(PSK/AES/AES) 
                   tfb_18_28 b0:c7:45:ac:18:98 -87  7,+1    Y  -- WPA2(PSK/AES,TKIP/TKIP) 
   HP-Print-93-LaserJet 1102 08:3e:8e:7c:04:93 -86  6       N  -- NONE
                   SG-OFFICE 74:d0:2b:dc:67:64 -80  6       Y  -- WPA2(PSK/AES/AES) 
                      holo15 b8:55:10:bd:3e:70 -82  5,-1    Y  -- WPA(PSK/AES/AES) WPA2(PSK/AES/AES) 
             TOTOLINK N300RA 78:44:76:dd:bb:b4 -82  5,+1    Y  -- WPA(PSK/AES/AES) WPA2(PSK/AES/AES) 
               ezstay 15F-28 78:44:76:dc:f1:a0 -85  2,+1    Y  KR WPA(PSK/AES/AES) WPA2(PSK/AES/AES) 
                      12F-32 20:10:7a:9f:d9:c1 -59  1       Y  -- WPA(PSK/AES,TKIP/TKIP)
```

The awk on airport command just cuts out the names of the Open networks and puts them on separate rows.

Comment: Any more suggestions? Please?

Comment: You might want to post some example output of `airport -s` for people who don't run OSX.

Comment: Will update topic with airport -s output!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
mapfile -t ssids < <(
    airport -s | 
    sed -E '
        1d
        /NONE$/!d
        s/^[[:blank:]]*(.+) [[:xdigit:]:]{17} (...).*/\2 \1/
    ' | 
    sort -k1,1nr | 
    cut -d " " -f2-
)
printf "%s\n" "${ssids[@]}"
```

```
HP-Print-93-LaserJet 1102
TPE-Free
```

---

adjusting for bash v3

```
ssids=()
while read -r line; do ssids+=("$line"); done < <(
    airport -s | 
    sed -E '
        1d
        /NONE$/!d
        s/^[[:blank:]]*(.+) [[:xdigit:]:]{17} (...).*/\2 \1/
    ' | 
    sort -k1,1nr | 
    cut -d " " -f2-
)
printf "%s\n" "${ssids[@]}"
```

Comment: May need bash v4 for `mapfile`, not sure.

Comment: Unfortunately getting this error in OSX: /Applications/connect.sh: line 19: mapfile: command not found

Comment: The bash on OSX is too old.

Comment: Try my edit now.

Comment: Great, thank you. 
Have a problem when trying to list the networks still that the network names are cut.. 
doing this for loop but still cutting on spaces, any suggestions?:
 
network_selection=1 
echo "These are the available open networks, sorted by signal strength:" 
for line in ${ssids[@]}
do
echo $network_selection ") " "$line"
let network_selection++
done

Comment: **Crucial** to use quotes: `for line in "${ssids[@]}"`

Comment: It looks like you're printing a list of choices. Investigate bash's `select` command to make your life easier.

Answer (score 5):

You should quote **netarray** in the *for-in* loop.

```
for hit in "${netarray[@]}"
do
     networks[$addloopnr]="$hit"
     let addloopnr++
done
```

Comment: I've tried that, but then what happens is that all networks found is added to networks[0]..

Comment: I need all networks found to be added to own array cells, and they are currently on own rows in $netarray

Comment: I'm thinking I need to use IFS but not really sure how to..

Answer (score 0):

just store the command result directly to an array

this does require fiddling with `IFS` to get it to split only on newlines

note that `$'\n'` for newline may be something of a `bash`-ism; ymmv w/`zsh`

```
OIFS=$IFS IFS=$'\n' netarray=(`airport -s |
awk '$NF=="NONE"{print}' | 
cut -c 1-32,51-54 | 
sort -r -n -k 1.34,1.36 | 
awk '{$NF=""; print}' | 
sed -e 's/ $//' `) IFS=$OIFS
```

e.g. based on your sample output,

```
$ typeset -p netarray
declare -a netarray='([0]="HP-Print-93-LaserJet 1102" [1]="TPE-Free")'
```

Comment: This is perfect for adding them directly to array, but problem is still that if a network name is "Network Name", Network will be in netarray[0] and Name will be in netarray[1]. That's the actual problem for me for which I think I need to use IFS somehow..

Answer (score 0):

I've used this on Linux. Omit the quotes on the array variable.  You can set IFS to the newline as follows:

```
IFS=$'\n'
netarray=`airport -s`
for hit in ${netarray[@]} ; do
    networks[$addloopnr]="$hit"
    let addloopnr++
done
```